# Generate PDF with image from database with mPDF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mpdf

I have an issue with a view and generated content to produce a PDF.At the moment, I've been working with mpdf\mpdf , but when i want to show the image on the view , error occurs .

My controller :

```
$view = View::share('data', $data);
$mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'mode'=>'UTF-8','format' => [400, 400],'autoScriptToLang'=>true,'autoLangToFont'=>true
]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf',compact('data')));
```

My blade :

```
<img src="/frontend/assets/images/cv/{{$data['seeker']->image}}">
```

Comment: "error occurs" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it works for mpdf however when i use this for dom pdf it works fine.

Change this in your blade

```
<img src="{{public_path('/frontend/assets/images/cv/' . $data['seeker']->image)}}">
```